# didEnterRegion order of execution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, uilocalnotification, region

So I asked a question about my code relating to didEnterRegion but perhaps I was being too specific, therefore could I ask someone to clarify the order of method calls in more generic terms for region monitoring, specifically when the app is in the background.

My understanding is:

1. App registers region calling startMonitoringForRegion:
2. User taps home button or locks device, app goes into the background.
3. The devices location is monitored at the OS level, separate from  the app, the app is never launched by the OS to confirm the users current location.
4. When the user crosses the boundary into the region, the OS looks for which app originally registered the region and launches that app.
5. The app is launched in the background, (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is not called however), the CLLocationManager delegate is setup and it’s didEnterRegion delegate method is called.
6. In my case, this sets up a UILocalNotification which is presented immediately (banner displays on home screen if for example another app is in use, or on the lock screen if phone is dormant).
7. The user actions the notification by swiping in the lock screen or tapping the banner, the app is launched and appWillEnterForeground/appWillBecomeActive is called AND the app delegate didRecieveLocalNotification: method is called if implemented.

This is my understanding, which is probably wrong as my UILocalNotification is never fired if the app is in the background. Could someone clarify which bits are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After further testing I've come to the conclusion that there's nothing wrong with my code and it's actually appears to be Apples implementation of region monitoring being poor. It seems to be only slightly better than the monitoring of significant location changes, and still relies on changes in wifi networks and cell towers. Even within a major UK city I found didEnterRegion wasn't trigged until you were up to 1000 meters into a mile wide region, if triggered at all. This explains why it works every time when testing though Xcode and forcing the location.

The only work around I've come up with so far is to calculate the distance remaining each time the users location is updated and to manually call the didEnterRegion delegate method when this is less than the regions radius/2. This is supposed to be done automatically by Apples code when you're more than 10m into the boundary, however I found that to be unreliable for the reasons above.

However given you can't get regular updates using the better accuracy of GPS whilst the app is in the background and this is only a problem when the app is in the background, it's not really a solution at all.  :o(